# how could we know that a theorem is suitable for proof by induction?

Tags: induction

Theorems like (factorization theorem) aren't suitable to be proven with induction since induction requires that the property tackled with our set of variables must be satisfied consecutively; (prime numbers aren't consecutive). So, how could we be sure that any theorem that we want to prove by induction, would be suitable for that? 
Is the answer: If it was proven as a false theorem by induction?

Comment: Actually, the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) is often proven using induction.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cm0io4R0tOM     at 22:40 this is what I meant when I talked about prime numbers

Comment: The trivial answer is that statements of the form $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: I(n),$$ where $I(n)$ is any statement, are the things to prove via induction. But there are of course more possibilities.